Wrong colors on mobile when using Nextjs v14 with SVGR
I am experiencing a weird problem with my application where i have SVGs which are being rendered as inline SVGs using a custom next.config.js with SVGR and webpack. The problem is that some of the svgs look alright on desktop viewport but they lose colors when on less viewports like when we're on mobile.
On Mobile
On Desktop
Here is my custom next.config.js file:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config) {
    // Grab the existing rule that handles SVG imports
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) =>
      rule.test?.test?.(".svg"),
    );

    config.module.rules.push(
      // Reapply the existing rule, but only for svg imports ending in ?url
      {
        ...fileLoaderRule,
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        resourceQuery: /url/, // *.svg?url
      },
      // Convert all other *.svg imports to React components
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: fileLoaderRule.issuer,
        resourceQuery: { not: [...fileLoaderRule.resourceQuery.not, /url/] }, // exclude if *.svg?url
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
      },
    );

    // Modify the file loader rule to ignore *.svg, since we have it handled now.
    fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/i;

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(nextConfig);


I am using next.js v14 and @svgr/webpack v8.1.0.
I am stuck for so much time, any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks!
I have tried some solutions, even moving to babel-plugin-inline-react-svg but some of nextjs features are only supported on SWC, apart from that I did not find anything related to this online.
